# Select em duas tabelas com condições específicas

Tags: sql, select

Olá, tenho 2 tabelas e gostaria de uma ajuda com as condições do select

```
SELECT top 100 t1.Killer, t1.Victim, t1.KillDate, t2.Name, t2.G_Name              
FROM C_PlayerKiller_Info t1 INNER JOIN GuildMember t2 ON (t1.Killer = t2.Name)  
WHERE t1.Killer = t2.Name 
order by Killdate desc
```

Tenho esse resultado:

[image: Resultado]

Eu não estou sabendo como fazer uma condição específica:

- Preciso que o G_Name do Killer seja diferente do G_Name do Victim

**Exemplo:** Eu tenho 5 jogadores: Player1, Player2, Player3, Player4 e Player5.

Os jogadores Player1, Player2 e Player3 pertencem ao Clã XXXX Os jogadores Player4, Player5 pertencem ao Clã YYYY

Caso o Player1 mate o Player2, o resultado da query vai retornar o G_Name XXXX Eu não quero que o resultado da query mostre que os jogadores do clã XXXX se mataram entre sí.

Gostaria que o resultado retornasse apenas se o Player1 matasse um jogador do clã YYYY.

Alguém pode me auxiliar com isso? obrigado!

Comment: `t1.Killer <> t1.Victim`???

Comment: Vou esclarecer melhor na resposta da pergunta

Comment: edite e adicione a pargunta, respostas são usadas para responder a pergunta não para adicionar detalhes, se não souber como editar, há um link "Editar" abaixo da pergunta :)

Answer (score 0):

Boa noite. Tentei entender o que foi feito, e devido a normalização (ou a falta dela) fica um pouco mais trabalhoso de acompanhar o raciocínio. Ainda assim, reproduzi o que você fez e tentei chgar a uma possível aproximação do resultado que você esperava.

Reprodução do cenário
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Aproximação do resultado
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]